# I'd like to inject Repositories container at Service constructor using typedi

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, typedi

I'd like to inject Repositories at my UserService.

But i'm not sure how to do that.
I'm using typescript, typedi and sequelize.

I think, the Service is loaded more fast than loaders.

When I try to inject my Repositories which I set at database loader, the error occur.

The error like this : **ServiceNotFoundError: Service with "repositories" identifier was not found in the container. Register it before usage via explicitly calling the "Container.set" function or using the "@Service()" decorator.**

So, I checked "userRepo" with console.log and the result was undefined.
I also checked Container.get('repositories') at CreateUser meathod, it loaded collectly. I mean, I can get my Container instance.

I just can't load repositories instance at constructor.

What should I do to load repositories at constructor?
Should I change sequelize to typeorm to load this?

```
// ** UserService.ts **
import { Inject, Service } from 'typedi';
import { UserRepository } from '../repositories/user.repository';
import { UserCreationAttributes } from '../models/interface/User.interface';
import { User, UserModel, UserStatic } from '../models/User';

@Service()
export default class UserService {
  constructor(@Inject('repositories') private userRepo: UserRepository) {}

  public async CreateUser(userData: UserCreationAttributes): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      await this.userRepo.create(userData);
      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```
// ** Database Loader **
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import config from '../config';
import Logger from './logger';
import { UserStatic } from '../models/User';
import { FeedStatic } from '../models/Feed';
import { CommentStatic } from '../models/Comment';
import { VerificationStatic } from '../models/Verification';
import { initializeModels } from '../models';
import { initializeRepositories, Repositories } from '../repositories';
import { Container } from 'typedi';

export interface Models {
  User: UserStatic;
  Feed: FeedStatic;
  Comment: CommentStatic;
  Verification: VerificationStatic;
}

export default async function loadSequelize() {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.databaseUsername,
    config.databasePassword,
    {
      host: config.databaseHost,
      port: config.databasePort,
      dialect: 'postgres',
    },
  );

  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    const models: Models = initializeModels(sequelize);
    const repositories: Repositories = initializeRepositories(models);
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });

    // This part might be loaded after services were loaded
    Container.set('models', models);
    Container.set('repositories', repositories);


    console.log('load finish');
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.error(err);
  }
}
```

```
// ** ./repositories/index.ts **
import { Models } from '../loaders/database';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';

export interface Repositories {
  UserRepository: UserRepository;
}
export const initializeRepositories = (models: Models): Repositories => {
  const usersRepository = new UserRepository(models.User);
  const repositories: Repositories = {
    UserRepository: usersRepository,
  };
  return repositories;
};
```

```
// ** ./repositories/base.repository.ts **
import { Model, BuildOptions, FindOptions } from 'sequelize/types';
import { IFilter } from './filter/base.filter';

export type RichModel = typeof Model & {
  new (values?: Record<string, unknown>, options?: BuildOptions): Model;
};

export interface IMeta {
  globalCount: number;
  countAfterFiltering: number;
}

export interface IWithMeta<M extends Model> {
  meta: IMeta;
  data: M[];
}

export abstract class BaseRepository<
  M extends Model,
  C extends object,
  F extends IFilter = IFilter
> {
  constructor(public _model: RichModel, private filterFactory: new () => F) {}

  private async getCount(where?: Record<string, unknown>): Promise<number> {
    const count = await this._model.count({ where });
    return count;
  }

  async getAll(params?: FindOptions, filter?: F): Promise<IWithMeta<M>> {
    const { from: offset, count: limit } = filter || {};
    const result = await this._model.findAndCountAll({
      order: [['id', 'ASC']],
      offset: offset,
      limit: limit,
      ...params,
    });

    const globalCount = await this.getCount();
    const countAfterFiltering = ((result.count as unknown) as Record<
      string,
      unknown
    >[]).length;

    return {
      meta: { globalCount, countAfterFiltering },
      data: result.rows as M[],
    };
  }

  async getById(id: string | number): Promise<M> {
    const result = await this._model.findByPk(id);
    return result as M;
  }

  async get(where: Record<string, unknown>): Promise<M> {
    const result = await this._model.findOne({ where });
    return result as M;
  }

  async updateById(id: string | number, data: C): Promise<M> {
    const result = await this._model.update(data, {
      where: { id },
      returning: true,
    });

    const [, models] = result;

    return models[0] as M;
  }

  async deleteById(id: string | number): Promise<void> {
    await this._model.destroy({
      where: { id },
    });
  }

  async create(data: C): Promise<M> {
    const model = await this._model.create(data);
    return (model as unknown) as M;
  }
}
```

```
// ** ./repositories/user.repository.ts
import { BaseRepository, IWithMeta, RichModel } from './base.repository';
import { UserModel, UserStatic } from '../models/User';
import { UserCreationAttributes } from '../models/interface/User.interface';
import { IFilter } from './filter/base.filter';
import { UserFilter } from './filter/user.filter';
import { Service } from 'typedi';

@Service()
export class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<
  UserModel,
  UserCreationAttributes,
  IFilter
> {
  constructor(private model: UserStatic) {
    super(<RichModel>model, IFilter);
  }

  async getAllUsers(): Promise<IWithMeta<UserModel>> {
    const users = await this.getAll();
    return users;
  }

  async getOneByFilter({
    email,
    password,
  }: UserFilter): Promise<UserModel | null> {
    const user = await this.model.findOne({
      where: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    });
    return user;
  }

  async getAdminOneByFilter({
    email,
    password,
  }: UserFilter): Promise<UserModel | null> {
    const user = await this.model.findOne({
      where: {
        email,
        password,
        isAdmin: true,
      },
    });
    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to install and import `reflect-metadata` at the top level of your app?

Comment: @WitaloBenicio Yes, I already added my app.ts that on top. That's why I don't solve the error :(

Comment: Can you add your repository code?

Comment: @WitaloBenio Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to put your `initializeRepositories` call right after the `reflect-metadata` call, to test if the execution order will impact. You don't need to call inside the database connection file.

From what I saw at the old docs, to use `Container.set` to set all of your repos, you need to provide an array containing objects with id for them.

`Container.set([{ id: 'userRepository', value: new UserRepository() }])`

If you just need to set a single repository:

`Container.set('userRepository', new UserRepository())`

In both cases above, you use like: `Container.get('userRepository')`;

If you want to keep the reference as `repositories` your `initializeRepositories`  method is ok, but the usage must be like:

```
@Inject('repositories') repositories: { UserRepository: UserRepository}; 

repositories.UserRepository
```

If you don't need to set your repositories from that method you can just put a decorator `@Service('userRepository')` in your `UserRepository` class and it will work.